How do I deal with this issue in Ubuntu: unmet dependencies error?
I am quite new to Ubuntu; I am facing a problem when trying to update or install anything.
I have tried everything I've found on the internet with no luck.
I don't do fresh start as I have some important apps and files that I have no idea how to reinstall.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  dictionaries-common :
Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not installed  libhtml-form-perl
: Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed 
libhtml-tree-perl : Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not
installed  liblwp-protocol-https-perl : Depends: libio-socket-ssl-perl
but it is not installed  libwww-perl : Depends: libhtml-parser-perl
but it is not installed
Recommends: libmailtools-perl but it is not installed  xserver-xorg-core : Depends: keyboard-configuration but it is not
installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with
no packages (or specify a solution).

This is the error message:


BTW, you will likely need to start the command with sudo, i.e., sudo apt --fix-broken install and sudo apt --fix-broken install.

Also, before running apt --fix-broken install you might want to do an "apt update" to pull the latest version of packages, which can help with dependencies.

Thank you for your replies, I have tried sudo apt --fix-broken install and sudo apt --fix-broken install but it didnt work.
I have also tried to remove those packages but when restarting it boots into CLI, tried "startx" command but gives an error and logout

I cannot see a way to determine which version of Ubuntu this is?  sudo apt -s full-upgrade aiming towards 24.04(?), with at least one problematic custom package installed?

sudo apt purge dictionaries-common and then try again? More to come?

https://askubuntu.com/a/1521122/289138 + any applicable hints from the other answers in the same question?

it was "Jammy 22.04" I went with fresh installation and solve the issue
